# node global npm packages broke somehow (mac)

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

So I have node installed together with npm. And used the official installer from the website. But when I install a package globally like "express" for example it won't be available in command line.

Some information:

```
$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib/lib
└── express@4.17.1
```

But on the system the modules are in:

```
$ npm root -g
/usr/local/lib/lib/node_modules

$ ll
total 0
drwxrwxrwx   5 rudolfchrispens  admin   160B Jul 18 11:19 .
drwxrwxrwx  75 rudolfchrispens  admin   2.3K Jul 18 11:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 rudolfchrispens  admin    96B Jul 18 11:19 .staging
drwxr-xr-x   3 rudolfchrispens  admin    96B Jul 18 11:19 express
drwxr-xr-x  24 root             wheel   768B Jul  3 15:31 npm
```

My PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/lib

$ echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/bin
```

System:
macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132)

Problem:

```
$ express
-bash: express: command not found
```

I installed the package just using:

```
$ npm install express -g -loglevel=info
```

Without any errors...

What I already tried:

- uninstall completly
- rm all left files
- reinstall with official
  installer
- tried to change this property: 'npm config set
  prefix=/usr/local/lib' (since in some cases /usr/local/ seems to make
  problems because of rights

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: You don’t have `/usr/local/lib/bin` in $PATH. I suggest you undo the prefix change that doesn’t adhere to established filesystem hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

- Removed everything by hand with a tutorial.
- installed nvm via homebrew
- installed node 12 via nvm
- installed all my packages again (including npm install express-generator -g)
- everything works again!